# Write a program that creates a new data file that includes only the numbers from the first file that are greater than 60

Tags: c, file

I am writing a program that creates a new data file that will take the numbers from the first file that are greater than 60 and save them to a new file.

I have began with my code but for some reason it is not saving the numbers greater than 60. I am new to programming, still learning so any help will be very much appreciated. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int y;
FILE *DATA;
DATA = fopen("RN.txt","r");
    fscanf(DATA, &y);
if (y > 60)
{
    DATA = fopen("RN.txt","w");
    fprintf(DATA, y, "");
}
printf("Finished saving file RN.txt \n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? If you're tagging it a Java question just to bring attention to the question, it worked, but understand that some of that attention may be negative attention.

Comment: Java tag removed.

Comment: Well for starters, you need a loop of some sorts to read each line.  SO is not a tutorial site.  Sorry.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for C programming books.

Comment: A new file generally has a new name. You probably want to open it outside of whatever loop you have where you check for `>60` and either write or skip the number, and you're gonna need that loop.

Comment: Tagging [tag:c], [tag:c++11] and [tag:java] at the same time is very interesting. You can continue tagging like that if you want downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

There are several severe problems in your code.

My suggestions are as below:

1. Compile your program (preferrably with `-Wall`, enabling all warnings). You'll be getting a bunch of errors and warnings. Fix them carefully, one-by-one.
2. Learn [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
3. Throw what you have into the bin and read one of the [good C books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/5958455). Then restart from scratch.

---

A few insights:

1. You're using `fscanf()` and `fprintf()` wrongly:

   ```
   fscanf(DATA, "%d", &y);
   fprintf(DATA, "%d", y);
   ```
2. Opening the same file with two different handles to read and write at the same time will run yourself into troubles, *very quickly*. Close after reading or writing, or use another file for writing

   ```
   fclose(DATA);
   ```

   OR

   ```
   FILE *OUT = fopen("RN.out.txt", "w");
   ```
3. To repeat a specific process, you need a loop:

   ```
   while (fscanf(DATA, "%d", &y) > 0) {
       // process here
   }
   ```

Comment: I'd skip steps 1 and 2 there and go straight to 3!